# Microsoft Edge keeps showing message 'User denied request for Geolocation' even when I have enabled location for the site

Tags: javascript, geolocation, microsoft-edge

I have developed an application which saves user event and location on button click. This application works perfectly on other browsers except Microsoft Edge.
If the user denies request for geolocation once and wants to allow it the next time, then even after clearing cache, enabling location and managing permissions in  settings, the alert 'User denied request for Geolocation' keeps appearing on every button click. Any inputs, similar experiences and solution?

```
function button_click(){
  showPosition();
}
function showPosition(){  
    if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, 
       errorCallback, options);
    } else {
        alert('Geolocation not supported by your browser');
        document.cookie = "latitude=0.0";
        document.cookie = "longitude=0.0";
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
}

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    // timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

function successCallback(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(5);
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(5);    
    document.cookie = "latitude=" + latitude;
    document.cookie = "longitude=" + longitude;  
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

function errorCallback(error){
    switch (error.code){
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is not available.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break; 
        default:
            alert("Unkown error.");
    }    
    document.cookie = "latitude=0.0";
    document.cookie = "longitude=0.0";
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); 
}
```

I do not want the alert 'User denied request for Geolocation' to keep appearing every time even after the user has enabled location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to make a test with your code on **Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0**

Based on my testing result, It is displaying the alert 'User denied request for Geolocation' every time after user deny to share the location on first time.

Reason is that MS Edge remember that user choice and do not again prompt the user for sharing the location.

If user want to share the location than

(1) User need to go to **Settings and more -> Settings -> Advanced -> Manage permissions**

(2) Select the site from the list and click on it.

(3) Turn on the location toggle button.

[image]

After that it will work properly and it will not display the error message.

Comment: Does it continue to work normally if you deny permission for location once and allow the next time?

Comment: Well it is working fine on my side. Can you please again check by following the steps above?

Comment: I have been trying the same thing for the past few days. It works for once and then it doesn't work the next time. But thank you for trying.

Comment: This is the testing result you can see from my side. https://i.postimg.cc/wBNWT1G9/53.gif